# Can I say that someone creates a tendency?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, meaning-in-context

> The lectures on Big data have received positive responses not only
>   from MIS students, but also from students of other majors, even
>   triggering a tendency of technology learning.
>
> I have given a series of lectures on Big data….,
>   creating/triggering/generating a tendency of technology learning.

I mean that after these lectures, technology courses suddenly became very popular among students. I am hesitant to describe the newly arisen fervor for technology as “tendency”, because tendency seems to be more universal, spontaneous, and unconscious. Also, I am not sure whether in the second sentence it makes sense to say that someone creates a tendency. Another word I can think of to emphasize the dramatic effect of these lectures is “wave”.

Answer (score 1):

No, "trend" would be better than tendency in this context. This is how I would phrase it:

> The lectures on big data have been received positively by MIS
>   students, as well as by students of other majors, starting a
>   trend of technology learning.

Comment: *trend* is far better than *tendency*, but it might be too soon to call the sudden influx of students from other majors a "trend". A BigData guru would have to be extra careful when using such terms, I would think. Perhaps OP's "wave" would be a safer choice?

Comment: @TRomano I smiled at "BigData guru" as it reminded me of "rock star programmer". In many ways, BigData is a "fad" or "trendy" more than a trend. True, a "wave of interest" would make more sense, but OP didn't ask for that. Fortunately, these words aren't associated with quantities nor metrics, so it isn't necessary to be extra careful with word choice pertaining to BigData, well, not more than any other subject of study.

Answer (score 1):

I would phrase it as,

> The lectures on Big data have received positive responses not only from MIS students, but also from students of other majors, even **sparking an interest in** technology learning.

Comment: That reads a lot better! Even "technology learning" is a weird phrase to my ear.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing really wrong with *tendency* there, except that it would be a tendency *for* (or toward) something, not *of* it. But there's not much right about it either.

Personally, I would prefer *an affinity for* or simply just "an interest in technology learning."